# connecting three functions in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing a scrapy spider in which there are 3 functions. First function is collecting the links and from each link 2nd function again extract more links on a different page whose links are extracted in 1st function and 3rd function extracts the data from the links extracted in 2nd function. Kindly help me in this regards.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
#from scrapy.http import Request

class ScotlandSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scotland'
    allowed_domains = ['www.whoownsscotland.org.uk']
    start_urls = ['http://www.whoownsscotland.org.uk/search.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//p/a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            absoulute_url = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(absoulute_url , callback=self.parse_links)


    def parse_links(self , response):
        cities = response.xpath('//*[@id="layout-right"]/table/tr/td/p/a/@href').extract()
        for city in cities:
            absoulute_url_new = response.urljoin(city)
            yield scrapy.Request(absoulute_url_new , callback=self.parse_cities)

    def parse_cities(self , response):
        record = response.xpath('//*[@id="layout-left"]/table/tr')

        estate =  record[0].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        courty =  record[1].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        grid_ref =  record[2].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        acreage =  record[3].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        os_15 =  record[4].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        owner  = record[5].xpath('.//th/text()').extract() 
        owner_address = record[6].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        property_address = record[7].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        website  = record[8].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        further_info = record[9].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
        contacts = record[10].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
        regsiters_sheet = record[11].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
        regsiters_certificate = record[12].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
        currency_of_data = record[13].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()



        yield{
        "Estate" : estate,
        "County" : courty,
        "Grid Reference" : grid_ref,
        "Acreage" : acreage,
        "OS 1:50k Sheet" : os_15,
        "Owner" : owner,
        "Owner Address" : owner_address,
        "Property Address" : property_address,
        "Website" : website,
        "Further Information" : further_info,
        "Contacts" : contacts,
        "Registers of Scotland Sasines Search Sheet No" : regsiters_sheet,
        "Registers of Scotland Land Certificate No" : regsiters_certificate ,
        "Currency of Data" : currency_of_data
        }
```

Comment: Your code should work, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is full code on how to pass data between various functions, note the `meta` key in `Request()`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
#from scrapy.http import Request

class ScotlandSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scotland'
    allowed_domains = ['www.whoownsscotland.org.uk']
    start_urls = ['http://www.whoownsscotland.org.uk/search.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//p/a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            absoulute_url = response.urljoin(link)

            data_to_pass = {"absoulute_url": absoulute_url}

            yield scrapy.Request(absoulute_url , callback=self.parse_links, meta = {'data': data_to_pass})


    def parse_links(self , response):

        passed_data = response.meta['data']

        cities = response.xpath('//*[@id="layout-right"]/table/tr/td/p/a/@href').extract()
        for city in cities:

            passed_data['city'] = city

            absoulute_url_new = response.urljoin(city)
            yield scrapy.Request(absoulute_url_new , callback=self.parse_cities, meta = {'data': data_to_pass.copy()})

    def parse_cities(self , response):

        passed_data = response.meta['data']

        record = response.xpath('//*[@id="layout-left"]/table/tr')

        estate =  record[0].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        courty =  record[1].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        grid_ref =  record[2].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        acreage =  record[3].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        os_15 =  record[4].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        owner  = record[5].xpath('.//th/text()').extract() 
        owner_address = record[6].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        property_address = record[7].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        website  = record[8].xpath('.//th/text()').extract()
        further_info = record[9].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
        contacts = record[10].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
        regsiters_sheet = record[11].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
        regsiters_certificate = record[12].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
        currency_of_data = record[13].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()

        passed_data["Estate"] = estate
        passed_data["County"] = courty
        passed_data["Grid Reference"] = grid_ref
        passed_data["Acreage"] = acreage
        passed_data["OS 1:50k Sheet"] = os_15
        passed_data["Owner"] = owner
        passed_data["Owner Address"] = owner_address
        passed_data["Property Address"] = property_address
        passed_data["Website"] = website
        passed_data["Further Information"] = further_info
        passed_data["Contacts"] = contacts
        passed_data["Registers of Scotland Sasines Search Sheet No"] = regsiters_sheet
        passed_data["Registers of Scotland Land Certificate No"] = regsiters_certificate
        passed_data["Currency of Data"] = currency_of_data
```